# How to share JSP pages in more then one project?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to find a way to share JSP pages in more then one page?

Example we have the following projects:

```
commmon
projectA
projectB
```

The common project has all the CSS, images and two JSP pages.  header.jsp and footer.jsp which all the projects in my firm is going to use.

We try adding:

```
<jsp:include page="/common/webapphead.jsp" />
```

to projectA and projectB but it still cant find the header, But if I goto

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/common/webapphead.jsp
```

The page does display.

Comment: If you're on servlet 3 you can try [META-INF/resources](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/web_inf_lib_jar_meta).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "project"? That is probably terminology specific to your IDE. What is the structure of the resultant war file that gets deployed to the app server?

Comment: I mean two war files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use JSTL. Use the c:import tag.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<c:import url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/common/webapphead.jsp" />
```

Alternatively if you can enable cross context access, then you could use

```
<c:import url="/webapphead.jsp" context="/common" />
```

Look at 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: can you please post a example.. it would help